# git automatic files tracking

Tags: git, tracking, gitignore

I'm a new git user. 
I know about `.gitignore` files and `git add .`  command.

Lets assume I have many files in the project beside the ignored ones. And I want to stage SOME files each time they are changed and OTHER depending on the situation.

Is there an analogue of `.gitignore` file but for doing the opposite - staging files from list if they are changed? Or it violates the git idea?

My problem here is: it is very time consuming to add all those files I'm permanently intrested in one by one. But editing `.gitignore` each time is

1. also time consuming
2. git will not give me a hint which of the files were changed if they are in currently in the ignore-list.

P.S. I don't really want to solve it via writing bash script - I'm interested in git solutions for now.

Comment: Similar concept, but `git add directory` is actually recursive.